# Linq query and multiple where clauses with OR only first condition gets evaluated

Tags: c#, linq

I give a user flexibility by providing either username or user id, which are different database fields, both strings. Here is my Linq query below:

```
var usr = ctx.Users.Where(a => (a.Username.Equals(id) || a.UserID.Equals(id))).ToList();
```

The thing is if I call it with username: "johndoe", I get a record back, but if I user UserID: "12345" then I do not get any records back even though there is a user "johndoe" with id "12345" in the database.

Also if I change it to:

```
var usr = ctx.Users.Where(a => a.UserID.Equals(id)).ToList();
```

It works fine with UserID; "12345". So it seems that only first condition gets evaluated. Can't figure out what am I doing wrong...

Just to make things clear: I want to check both fields for the given id value and return the record where either field matches the id.

The final result I want to get is to have a record(s) returned in my usr variable regardless of which field, Username or UserID matches the input id.

Comment: The username and the userid are filled by the same input?, e.g Look at your first condition that you're checking both clauses by id. Shouldn't it be by username and id respectively?

Comment: @RobertoDeLaParra No. OP says they want to check both with the same value.

Comment: Why is your ID in the database a string? Are you sure it isn't an `int`?

Comment: yes, I am sure it is a string. I could explain to you why it was that way but I feel that it will take a lot of time and is irrelevant to the solution for the problem. The field is in the database and cannot be changed. I just have to use it. I also do not always agree with how things are set up but powerless to change it. Sad fact of life

Comment: @ElenaDBA And you want to check the `id` variable against both `username` and `userId`?

Comment: Roberto De La Parra, krillgar is correct - I want to check the same value against both fields and return records where either of the fields matches the value

Comment: @Magnus, yes, you are 100% correct

Comment: It looks OK to me, I'd use a SQL profiler to see what SQL command is actually being sent to your database server.

Comment: is it johndoe in the database lowercase too? Can you check that it doesn't have whitespaces to the end?

Comment: Debug it again and make sure the Id is what you expect it to be. The code is correct.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that `id` was the same for the query with the user name check and without the user name check and you got different results.

Comment: I checked - no whitespaces

Comment: @ElenaDBA lowercased too? Can you share your User class?

Comment: @ElenaDBA what happen if you revert your classes so: `id.Equals(a.Username) || id.Equals(a.UserID)`

Comment: @ElenaDBA just wondering what happens if someones username is "12345"

Comment: @johnny, it will return that record

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your linq query looks ok to me

```
public class Users
    {
      public string Username {get;set;}
      public string Userid {get;set;}
    }

void Main()
{
    var users = new List<Users>{new Users {Username="johndoe",Userid="123"},
                                new Users {Username="stevejobs",Userid="456"}
                                };

    var filter = users.Where(a => (a.Username.Equals("123") || a.Userid.Equals("123"))).ToList();
    filter.Dump();
    var filter2 = users.Where(a => (a.Username.Equals("456") || a.Userid.Equals("456"))).ToList();
    filter2.Dump();
}
```

Comment: Your example is doing Linq to Objects, where as the OP seems to be using a Linq to SQL provider.  Those can behave very differently (though in this case they shouldn't).

Comment: I agree, but this is an example just to show that the OP's linq query is right and maybe OP needs to concentrate on his attention elsewhere

Comment: No, I just checked - no whitespaces

Comment: what happens when you reverse the order of checks? like `ctx.Users.Where(a => (a.UserID.Equals(id) || a.Username.Equals(id))).ToList();`

Comment: @ElenaDBA Did this answer solve it? What was the problem?